# how to get te 2. element of the 11. line with python?

Tags: python, split

I have a text file, and I want to save the second elemnt od the 11th lines as an element.
The file looks like this:

```
WIDTH: 32554
```

I am trying to get it with this:

```
 z = open('abcd.txt')
 lines = z.readlines()
 print(lines.split(' ', 1))
```

Comment: 10th line or 11th line?

Comment: Sorry i mean 11th ;)

Comment: Then edit the question, and fix the spelling while you do it.

Comment: @Krsztr and what do you get if you run your code? `print(lines[11].split(' ')[0])` is not enough?

Comment: @krsztr I added an answer. Please accept it you it worked for you :)

Comment: This should be posted on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this at the end of your script to get the wanted information:

```
print(lines[11].split(' ')[1])
```

`lines[10]` - select to 11th element of lines array. Arrays are numbered from 0

`split(' ')[1]` - split line using space character and select second element